# Choosing alternate hypothesis in two sample t-test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, minitab, two-sample

I am trying to do two-sample T-test in Minitab where I have to compare average of one variable with another binary variable. I am having difficulty in choosing alternate hypothesis. So just for guessing I tried both ways H1: u1 > u2 and H1: u1 < u2. Both gave same values of t less than critical t value (that is I cannot reject null). But I got different p-values.

How do I know which alternate hypothesis is correct? I am missing some concept here, can anyone please explain it?

Comment: Does it matter? If I Understand right, the stats tell you you must reject both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not detect a significant difference.

If you are not sure which direction to test for, then you should have used a **two-tailed test**. Nevertheless, since both $p$-values are insignificant, the two-tailed test will also be. Hence, you cannot conclude a significant difference.

You also mention that you are comparing binomial variables. What made you conclude a $t$-test was appropriate for this; Are the variables approximately normally distributed?

Comment: I'm sorry I meant binary not binomial. I edited the question.

Comment: Okay I got what you mean, there is no significant difference either way.

Answer (score 0):

You don't choose your hypothesis from p-value, you choose whatever you require for your experiment. Once your hypothesis is chosen, you don't go back and change it just because the p-value is too high.

While you failed to reject your hypothesis with t-test. I think it's more important to check your statistical assumptions. Why'd you use a binomial variable for t-test?

Comment: I'm sorry I meant binary not binomial. I edited the question.